# How to speed up appending a dataframe from a list of jsons

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am making api calls and throwing the values into an empty list (about 1.8 million lines, Json format). I then am trying to append an empty pandas dataframe from this list. The problem is it is extremely slow taking between 2-6 minutes per batch of 10000 rows. Is there a way to make this code more efficient?

```
import time
count = 0 
t1 = time.perf_counter()
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in json_file:
    print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
    print(f'row {count})
    for k in i ['data']:
       df=df.append(k['data'],ignore_index = True)
       count += 1
       t2 = time.perf_counter
```

This is the format of my list of jsons

```
Out[20]: {'data':[{'data': {'NAMEHCR': 'MERRILL BANKSHARES CO', 
                            'REPDTE': '19840331', 
                            'NTCRCDQ': 8, 
                            'CRCRCD': 2, 
                            'LNCRCD5': 5431, 
                            'NTCRCDQR': 0.007265346341330512, 
                            'LNCRCD': 5311, 
                            'ASSET': 444738, 
                            'LNCRCD2': 5431, 
                            'EQ': 26393, 
                            'DEP': 308626, 
                            'NTCRCDR': 0.007265346341330512, 
                            'NTCRCD': 8, 
                            'DRCRCD': 10, 
                            'NTCRCDA': 32, 
                            'CERT': 8, 
                            'LNLSNET': 194948, 
                            'ID': '8_19840331'}, 
                            'score': 0},
```

API calls are done btw to clarify. I am only interested in figuring out a faster way to create the dataframe.

Comment: Can you probably collect all information required in `df` and then create a `df` at once? i.e. with out using `df.append`, create it at once.

Comment: `df=df.append` is very expensive. Instead, do `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(k['data']) for k in dic['data'])`

Comment: can you edit your json to be a valid json/dict.

Comment: @rafaelc Minor correction to your ans: `df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([k['data']]) for k in data['data']])`

Comment: That was definitly alot faster thank you!  ```df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([k['data']]) for k in i ['data']])``` small correction.